Help understanding a use case to develop a network topology
I am self learning networking and now want to create a simple network topology in containerlab. This is only for a simple test lab. For this I am only using OSPF and BGP. I have came up with a scenario to model like below;
I have 02 offices in different geo locations. Office A is in Location A and Office B is in location B. Office A has a router(R1), switch and a PC. Office B also same. I am going to use BGP between Office A's router (R1) and B's router(R2).
However, what I am not getting is how to update the use case to include OSPF as well. I am thinking about multi area OSPF.
Can I say in Office A we have 02 departments (different LANs) using separate routers (R1.1 and R1.2). R1.1 and R1.2 connects to switch and PCs respectively. so I can use OSPF between R1 (area 0), R1.1 (area 1) and R1.2 (area2) within Office A. If so for BGP all different LANS of Office A can be considered as a single AS.
Is this scenario correct or am I missing something here. I would like to have a clear scenario so that I can build the network topology on top of it and understand things better.
I kindly seek your advice.
Thank you!

You use routing protocols between adjacent routers. It won't work across a number of (Internet) routers not under your control.

Your scenario is OK, if a bit complicated given the small number of routers.  But for learning purposes it's fine.
In the real world, multiple OSPF areas are uncommon.  Areas were created to reduce the processing needs of routers at a time when router processing power and WAN circuit speeds were a fraction of what they are today.
A more realistic scenario might include at least one BGP router (and AS) between R1 and R2 to simulate a WAN provider (or the Internet).
